# How does the jQuery file upload plugin gain reference to file content in IE9?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-file-upload

So I understand that IE9 does not support the File API, which means that the file input element does not have a files property present on it. The FormData object also does not exist in IE9, so that can't be used to manually append together a set of fields into an upload. I've been pouring through the plugin code in real time and I still don't understand how it's doing it.

Does anyone know how or where exactly this plugin gains reference to or attaches the actual file content to its upload request in sans-File API IE9?

Comment: usually when a browser does not have file api, a flash fall back is used

Comment: You should link to the specific plugin you are referencing.  There is also a tag for "jquery-file-upload" that should add if it is the same plugin you are talking about.

Comment: you can post populated inputs without filereader since 1995 just by using a hidden form.

Comment: So it is capable of performing the POST direct from the form, but it does so without ever gaining direct reference to the raw file data? Unfortunate, because I was really rather hoping to be able to sneakily pull the file content out for other manipulation.